What Data.SqlClient can be used with .net 8
I am trying to create a new project using VS 2022 community - c# class library.
The project is using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. NuGet recommended to get version 5.8.2.
This did not work when using the DLL of the class library from a Console application c# targeting .net6. I was receiving an error
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform  

I then tried to lower the versions of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to 4.0.5 and when calling this class from a Console application I receive
ystem.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone suggest what combination of Tragert Frameword and Microsoft.DataSqlClient can work?
Thanks

Based on your situation, we have found that the latest version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. is 5.2.0, and there is no problem in testing on our machine. Can you provide a screenshot of yours so we can understand the problem more clearly.

DON'T POST SCREENSHOTS. Screenshots can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled. Post your actual code, actual full error and actual csproj file. There's nothing wrong with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient nor does it require .NET 8. The real problem seems to be that your library targets .NET 8 instead of .NET Standard or .NET 6, and so can't be used in a .NET project

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.2.0 works on all supported .NET Framework (4.6.2+) and .NET Core versions (6+).  You may have to add it to the executable project, not just the DLL though. There's a possibly related Github issue when Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is only added to DLLs, that can be solved by adding the package directly to the main project

This may be related to this Github issue that's not related to compatibility issues at all. The problem is caused when Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is added to a DLL but not the main (executable) application. In that case this error is thrown:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

The problem can be solved by adding the package directly to the main application, or adding the package reference to the main .csproj file :
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0" />

The problem seems to be that Microsoft.Data.SqlClient includes some native libraries that are only copied into the library project where the package is added. Adding a project reference to that library project doesn't also copy the libraries.

I built DLL to create apps for AutoCAD 2025.
Indeed, this error occurs when I use Microsoft.Data.SQLClient.
But in the folder: "....nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient\5.2.2\runtimes\win\lib\net8.0" there is another file Microsoft.DataSQLClient.DLL. Copy it to the \Bin folder and then it will work correctly.
I don't know why there are several different versions in the Nuget folder!!
If you create an EXE type app, these dependent DLLS are copied correctly to the folder. However, Class Library (dll) requires finding out which file is correct and then copying it manually. I also needed to copy:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Client.dll

